# what can be the best algorithm to find numbers with only single set bit and whose sum is equal to given number?

Tags: c, algorithm

Suppose i have one number `0b10110010`,

I want to parse it in different numbers whose sum is equal to above number, All parsed numbers should have only single bit set.

```
 10000000  <-- num1
 + 100000  <-- num2
 +  10000  <-- num3
 +     10  <-- num4
----------
 10110010  <-- num1 + num2 + num3 + num4
```

What can be the best algorithm for this?

Comment: Please choose *one* language for this task.

Comment: Doesn't `%10` then, `/10` work?

Comment: @FUZxxl I tagged c and c++, anyone is fine.

Comment: @vish4071 To indicate binary

Comment: @FUZxxl OP asks for an algorithm, so both language tags are wrong here.

Comment: Sorry...I got that...and deleted the comment

Comment: @JagsVG No, that's against policy. Please pick at most one.

Comment: @FUZxxl, c++ tag is removed.

Comment: @mch Rather: for questions regarding general algorithms or pseudo code, _no_ language tags at all should be used. Spamming multiple language tags in order to give such questions more attention is frowned upon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, something like this:

```
int i;
for (i = 1; i <= num && i != 0; i <<= 1) {
    if ((i & num) == 0)
        continue;

    /* i is part of the decomposition, do something with it */
    printf("0x%4x\n", i);
}
```

This iterates through all possible numbers with one bit set and ignores those for which the corresponding bit in `num` isn't set. The complexity is O(log *num*). There is also an O(*k*) solution where *k* is the number of 1 bits in *num*, the algorithm goes like this:

```
int i, n = num;
while (n != 0) {
    i = ((n - 1) & ~n) + 1;
    /* i is part of the decomposition */
    printf("%4x\n", i);
    n &= n - 1;
}
```

Consider the following diagram to understand how this works:

```
n             101101101010100000000
n - 1         101101101010011111111
~n            010010010101011111111
~n & (n - 1)  000000000000011111111
i             000000000000100000000
n & (n - 1)   101101101010000000000
```

In the last line, `n &= ~i` could also be used but that would force the compiler to retain the `i` variable for a bit longer than needed which may be less optimal for speed. Benchmark when in doubt.

My personal guess is that the second method is faster if *num* is sparse, i.e. only few bits are set in *num.* Due to its lower number of operations, you should use the first method if *num*  is known to not be sparse.

Comment: Why do you shift i by 2? It should be shifted by 1...(or multiplied by 2)

Comment: @FUZxxl Isn't it possible without O(n)?

Comment: This is not O(n),this is O(log(n))

Comment: @JagsVG First of all, this is O(log *n*) but practically O(1) as the number of a bits in an `int` is finite. Second, yes, it's possible to do in O(*k*) where *k* is the number of bits set but the method is more complex and doesn't really pay off. If you like, I can write it out, too.

Comment: @FUZxxl, Please write it.

Comment: Very nice answer, this is the optimal solution.

Comment: @FUZxxl Why ~i  is 111111111111100000000 when i is 000000000000100000000?

Comment: @JagsVG Because I refactored the code and forgot that part.